# How to add to IJ Idea project an extrenal library from Gradle repository?

Tags: intellij-idea, gradle

I have a gradle project succesfully imported to Intellij Idea 14.
There are some library dependencies pointing to ~/.gradle directory.
On the list of libraries in project structure window they appear with "Gradle:" prefix.

**My question is**: How to add another library in the same way?
In other words: How to "persuade" Gradle to find it in repo, download, link to my module and show with "Gradle:" prefix on the libraries list in project structure window?

Comment: See [Dependency Management Basics](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/artifact_dependencies_tutorial.html) in the [Gradle User Guide](http://gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/userguide_single.html).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I realized that it is impossible to set it from project properties GUI and then synchronize it to gradle script. Script tweaking is the only way to add library from gradle.